# Mapping flat surfaces to a calotte with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, surface

I'm quite new to opencv and would need some help with this. I would like to map a flat surface image onto a calotte, nothing extra maybe only black and white squares. Are there any good examples,snippets maybe even already existing programs that can do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

A [Riemann Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere)?

#### Solution for arbitrary shapes

Set up some world/projection matrices so that the "camera" is looking directly at the object in question. You can [steal the formula](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluLookAt.3G.html). Any point on the object which you "render" using this matrix will be mapped to the texture coordinate it should have when your render it for real.

Comment: To be more precise,I need to map a flat surface onto a calotte. Something very simple, view angle at the moment doesnt matter that much.

Comment: If the calotte is a section of a sphere then the Riemann projection is what you want. If it's something stranger then perhaps you'll have to tesselate and project the individual vertices.

Comment: Sounds good but how should I go about this? Are there some specific opencv funtions for mapping images to surfaces?